# Abstract type classes/interfaces in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to have superclasses/interfaces and subclasses/implementations that depict the typing in an abstract way?

Lets say you have types and following functions:

```
class Animal {
  name: string;
}
class Bird extends Animal {
  canFly: boolean
}
class Dog extends Animal {
  tailLength: number;
}

enum animals {
  bird = 'bird',
  dog = 'dog'
}

class AnimalDTO {
  type: animals;
  information: Animal;
}

function registerAnimal(animalDto: AnimalDTO) {
  if (animalDto.type == animals.dog) {
    petDog(animalDto.information);
  }
}

function petDog(dog: Dog) {
  console.log(`Petting ${dog.name} with tail length ${dog.tailLength}`)
}
```

Now in the registerAnimal function it complains

```
Argument of type 'Animal' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dog'.
  Property 'tailLength' is missing in type 'Animal' but required in type 'Dog'.
```

How can I have a function that accepts this global DTO and I can apply logic to, based on the passed type, project the passed information to the specific subclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to narrow the type of `animalDto.information` based on `animalDto.type`, which will only work if `animalDto` is a union of DTOs for specific animals (more on that below).

The usual way to do this is to not have an `Animal` base class, and instead have a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of specific animal types (this is called a [*discriminated union*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) — a union where you can tell the members apart by some characteristic [`name` in this case]):

```typescript
interface Bird {
    name: "bird";
    canFly: boolean;
}

interface Dog {
    name: "dog";
    tailLength: number;
}

type Animal = Bird | Dog;
```

(I've used interfaces there, but you could do it with `Bird` and `Dog` classes as well.)

That way, we can differentiate animals based on the type of their `name` (which is a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), `"bird"` or `"dog"`, not just a string):

```typescript
interface AnimalDTO {
    information: Animal;
}

function registerAnimal(animalDto: AnimalDTO) {
    const animal = animalDto.information;
    if (animal.name == "dog") {
        petDog(animal);
    }
}

function petDog(dog: Dog) {
    console.log(`Petting ${dog.name} with tail length ${dog.tailLength}`);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELCgE2QbwFDKHIhwC2EAXMgEQBGGm1A3AUQnCAGIA2AnlbQD2g7hA4sAvnjyhIsRCgAiggOa5WhEuSrVMq5huRg4wbgBkIIFWAAWVEAFdStaJOlheABxQBBEMFI4bmQAXjQGZAAfZGUVFhlwaHgkZD8AoMUAFQB5dSJkUBhBKECwYEEQKjTA7jc8GAcQBDKK5CgIFWAAZzlqoIAKDnTuRTBBKv8arOyASjy2Cp7kIZrQ5cmMsYA6QuLS8pAWfOAYZEGN7i2tFBCw3X05-Hz87zBY8+GZo6IpKXrG5oHZCvd56FRUWKPQwIRYiCBbbiqfoAAwAChAwGUrMgACQ4MFXMgQCTIADuwFsRhMwVEVkpeIJxlMFjpNgkyK+eAkQA)

If `AnimalDTO` has to have a separate `type`, you can do the same thing with it that I did with `Bird` and `Dog` above:

```typescript
interface BirdDTO {
    type: "bird";
    information: Extract<Animal, {name: "bird"}>;
}

interface DogDTO {
    type: "dog";
    information: Extract<Animal, {name: "dog"}>;
}

type AnimalDTO = BirdDTO | DogDTO;

function registerAnimal(animalDto: AnimalDTO) {
    if (animalDto.type == "dog") {
        petDog(animalDto.information);
    }
}
```

The `Extract` bit identifies the specific name with a `name` matching the `type` we're using for the DTO.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELCgE2QbwFDKHIhwC2EAXMgEQBGGm1A3AUQnCAGIA2AnlbQD2g7hA4sAvnjyhIsRCgAiggOa5WhEuSrVMq5huRg4wbgBkIIFWAAWVEAFdStaJOlheABxQBBEMFI4bmQAXjQGZAAfZGUVFhlwaHgkcKxFABUAeXUiIy9KGnosA1zQGEEoQLBgQRAqAFEADzAoRDAAHj8AoIAaXC0CugZqCQA+NwS5ZKVVDOz8XI9vHT0VEqIyiqqauuQmlrbO-0DuPpwBlf0xiaXfY6C50NTMR+jYufiYBxAEatrkKAQFTAADOci6JwAFBxutxFGBBFQIQ8sgBKHIbGDIaH3OEIgB0t1CYV0+nRC1yRG8YFiONh8ME+M2lTgfxAqJYuSkUjwXx+bOQ1NpqyosXJhgQtRBIgg+O4qkhAAMAAoQMDVKzIAAkOFW+IGEmQAHdgLYjCZgqIrGadXrjKYLNabBJFRy8BIgA)

If there are a lot of animals, repeating `"bird"` and `"dog"` in both places is error-prone, so we can use a generic type to create them:

```typescript
type MakeAnimalDTO<AnimalType extends string> = {
    type: AnimalType;
    information: Extract<Animal, {name: AnimalType}>;
}

type BirdDTO = MakeAnimalDTO<"bird">;

type DogDTO = MakeAnimalDTO<"dog">;

type AnimalDTO = BirdDTO | DogDTO;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELCgE2QbwFDKHIhwC2EAXMgEQBGGm1A3AUQnCAGIA2AnlbQD2g7hA4sAvnjyhIsRCgAiggOa5WhEuSrVMq5huRg4wbgBkIIFWAAWVEAFdStaJOlheABxQBBEMFI4bmQAXjQGZAAfZGUVFjwPb2QAWTgAawg-AKDFABUAeQAeLMDuXK8UCAAPSBBMAGdkerAoUBUAPlD1IiMKqhKg8u8WHtAYQShAsGBBECoAURqoRDBi-1KAGlwtSmQBsoqJdrcEivCsPPyu1Iz9y8K6Bmpj9zPYy+v0zPWcgoe9FTPeKJXw-bgfMLoC4FKIxVSXeIwBwgBDTWbIKAQFTAZrQfYACg42XBYEE-TBlwAlN0iMAYMhCRTSQA6EGhMK6fTU-A9HreMCxRnExQssYTKYzECUkZEKRSPBIlFokDIfmCgFUWLcwwIWb1EQQZncVT4gAGAAUIGBplZkAASHAA5k7CTIADuwFsRhMwVEVi9DqdxlMFn9NgkpuleAkQA)

There are lots of ways to do this, but the fundamental thing is to have a type-based way of differentiating the types from one another; in the above that's the `"bird"` and `"dog"` string literal types.

Comment: +1. I think it worth adding a link to [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) in typescript

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Thanks. I'm always put off that link because the page is very specific to functional programming and references Haskell a lot. Most people don't do functional programming. But still, probably best to have the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
enum EAnimalType {
  bird = 'bird',
  dog = 'dog',
}

interface IAnimal {
  name: string;
}

interface IBird {
    information: IAnimal;
    type: EAnimalType.bird;
    canFly: boolean;
}

interface IDog {
    information: IAnimal;
    type: EAnimalType.dog;
    tailLength: number;
}

class Animal implements IAnimal {
  name!: string;
}

class Bird extends Animal implements IBird {
  information!: Animal;
  type: EAnimalType.bird = EAnimalType.bird;
  canFly!: boolean;
}

class Dog extends Animal implements IDog {
  information!: Animal;
  type: EAnimalType.dog = EAnimalType.dog;
  tailLength!: number;
}

type AnimalDTO = IBird | IDog;

function petDog(dog: IDog) {
  console.log(`Petting ${dog.information.name} with tail length ${dog.tailLength}`);
}

function registerAnimal(animalDto: AnimalDTO) {
  if (animalDto.type == EAnimalType.dog) {
    petDog(animalDto);
  }
}

registerAnimal({ 
  type: EAnimalType.dog,
  information: { 
    name: 'Yaki' 
  },
  tailLength: 3,
});
```

Check the working code at: [www.typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4UwOwVwW2BRAghAljAhgGwCoE8AOYwA3gFCigBGKATgCbAC8wA5NfSwDTkXB0D2AcyasBgrjxABfUpOAoIAFzA0AZugDGRAJLI0WEnJAR0MMAC5gAZ0U0FggNxyZchcrWadAIVoMyvUAVVfhoMRRR%20CEtdVAxMJwCQRQILBD04vEIAOnY6BMSNdAgAMUxcS0p%20fkwwIvzpWQo3FXUtYG0AESFDRPkIYND0cMjo9Kx63mTCSyRYrEywLLEJikV0FEwAGUhBRQALS2gYShUJlwoNTHQrK2AxzHkYfBqzJVuY-Qf-XhMzAEJLDY7BBHM5GqBLtdbj56OAAB7KCB0W73R7PMCvRTvGF%20Ix9AZhCIQAF3ObxPFTVKzT4LHK%20ETUjIpOn0FbAQolMokyrVWoQM7gkCQm7ALrCMAIyDI0mfNEvSBY9pinq8IIhQmREn3NmUmb3WliBn65nLCnrLY7fYko4nGgCuSUmVxDrYADyIm0OOAAB8lUInHJVFAIBphhBgIRFGKABRiaJigCUKoukSsvKymCE0YABgAFMCKcIg4AAEmIYiyasGYayvzAUmAAHcUPtgGsNsAaiDW2WK%202Ld29lJswn7RQgyGw8AaGBBCgbCp7tGip8Oop%20JZ7i7XUnvk1VMBl2S1-wso7GMxGfMTUJd3iQJGYyvnevR3iZBRzqAZ3OFzQl8QwAUikepkgaQjcAEVYalEJBAb0daWCwACa6AANYoCw8G8FIkGTOa2yDpYADMeHSG%20QA)

Comment: Presumably the whole point of the DTO is to provide the animal information. Doing a hardcoded `tailLength` doesn't seem useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for your comment. I have improved but working on a better version

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of awkward to tell TypeScript that there is a relationship between the `type` and `information` properties. But you could define all possible relations in a separate type:

```js
class AnimalDTO {
    type!: animals
    information!: Animal
}

type AnimalDTOtype = {
    type: animals.bird,
    information: Bird
} | {
    type: animals.dog
    information: Dog
}

function registerAnimal<T extends keyof typeof animals>(animalDto: AnimalDTOtype) {
  if (animalDto.type == animals.dog) {
    petDog(animalDto.information);
  }
}
```